# When implementing Monte Carlo Tree Search for TicTacToe, do I simulate won states?

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, simulation, games

I'm trying to debug my MCTS implementation for TicTacToe (it doesn't block obvious wins for the opponent). I was wondering what the algorithm should do if it expands to a node which is a game over state. Should it continue to "simulate" that node and back-propogate the results up the tree or just ignore it if the node is chosen.

Comment: The game over states are the only states that give you a score in tic tac toe: win, lose, or draw.  Back propogating that information is important.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I understand that but I was wondering whether there was a difference between reaching a terminal state through random playout (not reflected in the game tree) vs through expansion of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic variant of MCTS doesn't require a special management for terminal states.

It just updates the score / number of visits depending on the result (win / lose) and proceeds with back-propagation.

It's a sort of **istantaneous playout/simulation** and cannot be skipped (allowing MCTS to converge to the game-theoretical value).

The algorithm can be improved (e.g. MONTE-CARLO TREE SEARCH SOLVER) using large scores (say +∞ / -∞) and *ad hoc* backpropagation / selection schemes:

[image: MCTS Solver]

> A special provision is  then  taken  when  backing  such  proven  values  up  the  tree. There are three cases to consider as shown in Fig. (we use the  negamax  formulation,  alternating  signs  between  levels).
>
> First,  when  a  simulation  backs up  a  proven loss  (−∞)  from a  child
>   `c` to  a  parent `p`,  the  parent  node `p`  becomes,  and  is labelled as, a proven win (∞), that is, the position is won for the  player at `p` because the  move played leads to  a  win  (left backup  diagram  in  the  figure).
>
> When  backing  up  a  proven win  (∞)  from `c` to `p`,  one  must,   however,  also  look  at  the other children of `p` to determine `p`’s value. In the second case, when  all  child  nodes  of `p` are  also  a  proven  win  (∞),  then the value of `p` becomes a proven loss (-∞), because all moves
>   lead  to  a  position  lost  for `p` (middle  backup  diagram  in  the
>   figure).
>
> However, the third case occurs if there exists at least one child with a value different value from a proven win. Then we cannot label `p` as a proven loss. Instead `p` gets updates as if a simulation win (instead of a proven win) were being backed up from node `c` (right backup diagram in the figure;
>   `v` and `u` indicate non-proven values). Non-proven values are backed
>   up as in regular MCTS.

---

1) Further details in [Monte-Carlo Tree Search in Lines of Action](http://www.ru.is/~yngvi/pdf/WinandsB10a.pdf) by Mark H.M. Winands, Yngvi Bjornsson and Jahn-Takeshi Saito.